# Tensorflow error: Minimum tensor rank: 1 but got: 1

Tags: tensorflow

I'm getting the following error trying to eval my model.

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Minimum tensor rank: 1 but got: 1 [[Node: ArgMax_1 = ArgMax[T=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_Placeholder_1_0, ArgMax_1/dimension/_40)]]`

Here is the relevant code

```
        # Predictions for the current training minibatch.
        train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(train_prediction, 1), tf.argmax(train_labels, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        for i in range(1000000):
            start_time = time()

            images, labels = get_batch(fifo_queue, FLAGS.batch_size)

            feed_dict = {
                train_images: images,
                train_labels: labels
            }

            _, loss_value, learn_rate, predictions = sess.run(
                [train_step, cross_entropy, learning_rate, train_prediction],
                feed_dict=feed_dict)

            duration = time() - start_time
              if i % 1 == 0:
                # Print status to stdout.
                 print('Step %d: loss = %.3f (%.3f sec)' % (i, loss_value, duration))

                 train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
                     train_images: images, train_labels: labels, keep_prob: 1.0})
                 print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))
                 train_step.run(feed_dict={train_images: images[0], train_labels: labels[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
```

`

I haven't been able to try much yet because I'm just getting my first model eval-ing and this error (indicating expecting 1 and got 1) is not overly helpful.

Comment: From what I see it seems fine, provided that the function `get_batch()` returns tensors with the right shapes. Try to take a look at [this](https://github.com/diogojapinto/tensorflow-through-examples/blob/master/2.3%20-%20Logistic%20Regression.ipynb) example, and compare the rest of the code (variales and placeholders definition, data tensor shapes, etc).

Comment: This code runs except for the eval part.  Argmax  is supposed to take the predictions and the actual labels or the label placeholder, it seems.  Wonder why this isn't working...

Comment: Just a thing, shouldn't the argument to argmax `train_labels_node` be the same that you use in your feed_dict (where you have simply `train_labels`?

Comment: That was just a typo.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: One difference between mine and the examples is I'm trying to evaluate after a short period of time for testing, and not after all epochs/steps have run.  This shouldn't matter, I would think but testing that now.

Comment: I'll try to clarify argmax, it may help: as you are using, what arrives at each invocation should be a 2D matrix, each row being a sample, and each column being the probability that a sample is of the class ith-column (`train labels` should have just one column set to 1 for each sample, and `train_prediction` a distribution of probabilities among the classes). So, `equal` is comparing, for each sample, the index of the column with the highest value, returning a boolean column.

Comment: You're right, that shouldn't matter. Check also the shapes of the placeholders and variables...

Comment: My labels are single integers: 0 or 1.  Maybe I should vectorize them...

Comment: Yes, for the setup you have you should use one-hot encoding. Argmax does nothing in there. Otherwise you would have to change your accuracy function (to use a threshold on the predictions, from that create a vector of zeros and ones, and now you could apply directly the tf.equals.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message isn't great, but looking at [the code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2c55490c6d6d361985dbb0565ab08a648c819949/tensorflow/core/kernels/argmax_op.cc#L61) might explain what's going on.

The issue arises because `train_labels` is (presumably) a one-dimensional vector. Dimensions are numbered from 0, so a vector only has a 0th dimension, but your invocation of `tf.argmax(train_labels, 1)` attempts to take the argmax in the 1st dimension, which doesn't exist.

In fact, there's no need to take the argmax of the labels at all. Instead, you can simply write:

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(train_prediction, 1), train_labels)
```